# Querystring vs. json data in a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, get

I am writing a project in Javascript using node.js, express and mongodb which includes an API for POSTing images to a server.

When GETting them, the necessary parameters goes in querystring, like:

```
domain.com/api/imgs?firstParam=XXX&secondParam=YYY
```

Am not sure about best way to send POST data. My ideas so far are :

Send data entirely in the querystring (except base64 encoded img itself which will be in POST data)

Reuse the GET parameters from the querystring (I need to update data in DB), then send the additional parameters with POST

What would be best practice in this situation?

Comment: @xShirase ok what code you want ?

Comment: Edited question itself - should be more understandable now. 
No code needed for this one in my opinion. 

Querystring data vs. POST json data. 
Pretty obvious I think:)?

Comment: Agreed, no code is needed. In fact, code would actually add needless noise to the question since the exact implementation doesn't matter.

Comment: Agreed, now it's much clearer, thanks for editing my edit ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most common on POST to use JSON.

Off the top of my head here are a few reasons why:

- querystrings are part of the url and url length has a limitation
- on querystings you should use url-encode
- it's rather difficult to have complex data(ex. nested objects or nested arrays even) on querystrings

Comment: Thanks for this explanation.